# Is it possible to create default values with EasyGui multenterbox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, easygui

I have an EasyGui multenterbox and I was wondering if there was a way to set a default value for the inputs in the GUI?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need **default_text argument**

Syntax : `enterbox(message, title, default_text)`

Argument : It takes 3 arguments, first string i.e message/information to be displayed, second string i.e title of the window and third is string which is default text

Return : It returns the entered text and None if cancel is pressed

[EasyGui default text](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-easygui-enter-box/amp/)